# Laravel Lucid whereHas by latest column in pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot, relationship

I have 3 tables : Orders ( id, name, surname, created_at and updated_at ), OrdersStatuses (order_id, order_status_name_id, created_at) and OrderStautsNames ( id and name ):
I have orders model which has method like this:

```
protected $appends = ['actual_status'];

public function orderProducts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderProduct::class);
}

public function statuses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(OrderStatusName::class, 'order_statuses')
        ->withPivot('created_at');
}

public function getActualStatusAttribute()
{
    return $this->statuses()->latest('set_at')->first();
}
```

I have problem with seraching all orders, where highest status id ( this info is in pivot table OrderStatuses, and I need name of this status which is in OrderStatusNames ) is like $statuses (this is an array with statuses ). I started do like this:

```
    $orders = Order::query();
    $orders->whereHas('statuses', function($query) use ($statuses) {
                $query->whereIn('order_status_name_id', $statuses);
            });
```

But it return me orders with not latest status, but this query search me throught all statuses... . Can i do this by latest status? I tryed to use current_status but I don't know how to get there.

Comment: What is `$statuses` that you are using in query ?

Comment: $statuses = constant(Order::class . '::' . strtoupper($this->constraints[$key]));  I'm sure this is good. $statuses is an array of satuses, and it is const in Order Model

Answer (score 0):

Add this relation to your Order Model

```
public function lastStatus()
{
    return $this->hasOne(OrderStatusName::class)->select('OrderStautsNames.*', 'order_statuses.order_id', DB::raw('MAX(order_statuses.set_at) as lastOrder'))->join('order_statuses', 'order_statuses.order_status_name_id', '=', 'OrderStautsNames.id')
}
```

Then eager load it

```
$orders = Order::whereHas('lastStatus', function ($query) use ($statuses) {
    $query->whereIn('OrderStautsNames.id', $statuses);
})->get();
```